# How to remotely execute myfun and a scattered vector by using Rmpi

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi

myfun is a user-defined function, for example,
myfun=function(x){x^3}.
Now I want to run myfun for a vector, say t=1:10, in parallel by using 3 slaves. My code looks as follows,

```
mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves=3)
source("myfun.R")
mpi.bcast.cmd(myfun) #broadcast myfun to slaves
x=1:10
grp=ceiling(seq_along(x)/3)
grp[10]=3
sx=split(x,grp)
mpi.scatter.Robj2slave(sx) #scatter x into 3 groups to slaves
y=mpi.remote.exec(cmd=myfun,sx) #this does not work!
print(y)
mpi.close.Rslaves()
mpi.quit()
```

The problem is, Rmpi won't execute myfun on scattered sx properly. In the manual, about command mpi.remote.exec it says

> ...used as arguments to cmd (function command) for passing their
>   (master) values to R slaves, i.e., if ‘myfun(x)’ will be executed on R
>   slaves with ‘x’ as master variable, use mpi.remote.exec(cmd=myfun, x).

Since 'x' is a master variable, does this mean it's not possible to execute the myfun for scattered x on slaves? If not, what's the right way to parallel-compute the above example by using Rmpi?

Answer (score 0):

Inside myfun, use

```
i <- mpi.comm.rank()
```

to pick off  a component of sx

```
myfun<-
function(x)
{
     i <- mpi.comm.rank()
     x[[i]]^3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the use of

```
mpi.bcast.cmd(myfun) #broadcast myfun to slaves
```

I think this should be

```
mpi.bcast.Robj2slave(myfun)
```

Notice the description in the [help files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpi/Rmpi.pdf).

There could be a second issue with your `myfun` as detailed by @zmirlig but it is hard to say without seeing the function's code.